# Getting "No current user" error in Amplify with Next.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, next.js, aws-amplify

I tried to implement a SSG application in Amplify with Next.js following [this tutorial](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/data-model/q/integration/next/#api-with-incremental-static-site-generation-ssg)
`pages/index.tsx` worked well. But `pages/posts/[id].tsx` doesn't work and showed the following error.

```
Server Error
Error: No current user

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
```

And also the console showed this error.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/posts/da53d1f3-775f-49c4-a311-d311f2e5623f 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

My code in `pages/posts/[id].tsx` is following.
May I have your idea how to resolve this error?

```
import { Amplify, API, withSSRContext } from "aws-amplify";
import Head from "next/head";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import awsExports from "../../aws-exports";
import { getPost, listPosts } from "../../graphql/queries";

Amplify.configure({ ...awsExports, ssr: true });

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const SSR = withSSRContext();
  const { data } = await SSR.API.graphql({ query: listPosts });
  const paths = data.listPosts.items.map((post: any) => ({
    params: { id: post.id },
  }));

  return {
    fallback: true,
    paths,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }: { params: any }) {
  const SSR = withSSRContext();
  const { data } = await SSR.API.graphql({
    query: getPost,
    variables: {
      id: params.id,
    },
  });

  return {
    props: {
      post: data.getPost,
    },
  };
}

export default function Post({ post }: { post: any }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  if (router.isFallback) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Loading&hellip;</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{post.title}</h1>
      <p>{post.content}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: getStaticPaths and getStaticProps are invoked during build time so the user will likely not be present since the user is not "logged in" when you run your build process. I have a repo using the new [Amplify Authenticator UI + Next SSR + getServerSideProps](https://github.com/siegerts/next-amplified/blob/amplify-ui/pages/index.js) on the `amplify-ui` branch that may help to get you unblocked.